# looking for a way to have to output of a cron to go to both stdout and log file

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I have some crons that i would like to have the output goto both stdout and a historical log file. Currently the cron looks like :

```
05 5 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/mycrons/cronDaily.php
```

cron sends me an email of the output when complete.

```
05 5 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/mycrons/cronDaily.php  >> /logs/cronDaily.log 2>&1
```

This sends to my logs successfully but i do not get an email.

So is there a way to do both of these (get an email and log to a file) ?

Thanks
Randy

Comment: what is your configuration to make the email be sent directly? Also, related and interesting: [Redirect crontab output to email](http://serverfault.com/a/472878/200076) - that is, use `tee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
05 5 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/mycrons/cronDaily.php 2>&1 | tee -a /logs/cronDaily.log
```